# asp.net core Dependency Injection into System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, type-conversion

I have a service and ILogger that I need to use in my TypeConverter but the constructor with the parameters isn't being used or fired and my logger and service remain null when converting the type.

```
public class ModelServiceVersionConverter : TypeConverter
    {
        private static readonly Type StringType = typeof(string);
        private static readonly Type VersionType = typeof(ModelServiceVersion);

        private readonly ModelServiceVersions modelServiceVersions;

        private readonly ILogger<ModelServiceVersionConverter> logger;

        public ModelServiceVersionConverter()
        {
        }

        public ModelServiceVersionConverter(ModelServiceVersions modelServiceVersions, ILogger<ModelServiceVersionConverter> logger)
        {
            this.modelServiceVersions = modelServiceVersions;
            this.logger = logger;
        }

        public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType) =>
            sourceType == StringType ||
            sourceType == VersionType ||
            base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);

        public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
        {
            if (value is null)
            {
                return this.modelServiceVersions.ServiceVersions.Last();
            }

            var modelServiceVersion = this.modelServiceVersions.ServiceVersions.FirstOrDefault(x => x == value.ToString());

            if (modelServiceVersion is null)
            {
                var errorMessage = $"Version {value} unexpected. No implementation of {nameof(IModelService)} for this version.";
                this.logger.LogError(errorMessage);
                throw new ArgumentException(errorMessage);
            }

            return modelServiceVersion;
        }
    }
```

The `ModelServiceVersion` class is really simple and has the `TypeConverter` attribute on it.

```
    [TypeConverter(typeof(ModelServiceVersionConverter))]
    public class ModelServiceVersion : ValueObject, IComparer<ModelServiceVersion>
    {
        private readonly string version;

        public static ModelServiceVersion New(string version)
        {
            return new ModelServiceVersion(version);
        }

        private ModelServiceVersion(string version) =>
            this.version = version;

        public static implicit operator string(ModelServiceVersion modelServiceVersion) => modelServiceVersion.version;

        public static implicit operator ModelServiceVersion(StringValues stringValues) => New(stringValues[0]);

        protected override IEnumerable<object> GetEqualityComponents()
        {
            yield return this.version;
        }

        public int Compare(ModelServiceVersion x, ModelServiceVersion y)
        {
            // TODO these rules can and will likely change
            var versionNumberX = FirstOrDefaultDigit(x?.version);
            var versionNumberY = FirstOrDefaultDigit(x?.version);

            if (y is null || versionNumberY is null)
            {
                return 1;
            }

            if (x is null || versionNumberX is null)
            {
                return -1;
            }

            if (versionNumberX == versionNumberY)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            return versionNumberX > versionNumberY ? 1 : -1;

            static int? FirstOrDefaultDigit(string versionString) =>
                versionString?.ToCharArray().FirstOrDefault(IsDigit);
        }
    }
```

The services are all registered with `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection`.

I have tried just registering as scoped but it's not firing the type converter constructor to inject the dependencies in.

`services.AddScoped<ModelServiceVersionConverter>();`

When being used in the action on the controller

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetPrediction([FromRoute] int decisionModelId, [FromQuery] ModelServiceVersion version, [FromBody] GetPredictionModelRequest.Request request)
        {
            var result = await this.predictionModelQueries.GetPrediction(new GetPredictionModelRequest(decisionModelId, request));

            return this.Ok(result);
        }
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: "not working" doesn't help us. In what was is it not working? How are you using it? Do you get error messages? Etc. etc.

Comment: No error messages no errors, the constructor isn't being used by the container when attempting to bind data to the type. The type converter convert from method is being fired

Comment: @DavidG I have added a better explanation above, thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have created a custom `Attribute` and applied it to a method or a class. Will constructor DI work in this case?

No. This is not supported unless you use [specific asp.net-core attributes like ServiceFilterAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0#dependency-injection).

So you need to redesign your classes or have static access to DI container `IServiceProvider`.